# Possible to use externally supplied session keys for SSH?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I have been playing around with key management / generation lately, and was wondering if I could manually supply my own session keys for individual SSH sessions.

I have tried looking through the sshd_config file to find anywhere I could do so, but I have not discovered a way.

May I know if anyone knows of a way to supply externally generated session keys for (Open)SSH?

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can never provide your own session keys with the SSH protocol, even if you're using a library, unless you control both the client and the server.  The reason is because almost all implementations use a Diffie-Hellman key exchange and derive session keys from the shared secret in a fixed, uniform way.

Thus, the only influence you can have on the session key is with the key pair that each side provides.  Since both sides are supposed to generate a random key pair, even if you controlled the client, the server would still generally pick a random key pair, and thus you wouldn't be able to force any particular value.

Even with the RSA key exchange algorithm specified in RFC 4432, the server creates an ephemeral key pair, and thus has influence over the key exchange hash and session keys.  As a practical matter, though, nobody implements this approach, because generating ephemeral RSA key pairs is substantially more expensive than generating Diffie-Hellman key pairs, and the forward secrecy properties are typically worse.

Only if you had full control over the client and server key pairs could you influence the keys completely, and even then, your session keys would have to be generated from the SSH key derivation function.  I'm not aware of any sort of library that lets you even influence the CSPRNG used in this case, so as a practical matter, this would require patching an existing library.  If you wanted to do that, I have nice things to say about libssh, and the Go library is also passable.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Yes, I am willing to write a private patch. What could I do if I preferably want to write in Python? Please share about libssh and Go too :)

Comment: You're basically changing the protocol at that point, so I'd recommend you also use a different port and a different banner (i.e., not starting with "SSH-2.0") so that nobody is confused by your custom protocol.  Paramiko is an option for Python, and I'd have to refer you to the documentation and the SSH RFCs (e.g. RFCs 4251 and 4252).  You'll need to read and understand those before changing the protocol.